# Load a JSON using Python and edit a key value and then save it and post it using request

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a JSON of the below format

```
{
  "board_title": "test",
  "read_only": false,
  "isIntegration": false,
  "board_bgtype": "board_graph",
  "created": "2017-08-16T06:40:47.158868+00:00",
  "original_title": "Revised_CID_Templating-test(cloned)",
  "modified": "2017-08-31T11:52:22.115661+00:00",
  "disableEditing": false,
  "height": 111,
  "width": "100%",
  "template_variables": [
    {
      "default": "identity",
      "prefix": "v1",
      "name": "env"
    }
  ],
  "created_by": {
    "disabled": false,
    "handle": "xx.com",
    "name": null,
    "is_admin": false,
    "role": null,
    "access_role": "st",
    "verified": true,
    "email": "xx.com",
    "icon": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/86fd6c17deba27cfc4081134a5bc0c6a?s=48&d=retro"
  },
  ...
}
```

I need to load this JSON using Python and edit the value of

```
"template_variables": [
  {
    "default": "identity"
```

To some other value, say:

```
default : "com"
```

I load it using Python script and traverse and print the key value pair but not able to understand how to modify it.

How can I assign a value to the first child of template variables and save the JSON in the same file and post it using request?

Comment: I used the below to just print the values : jsonFile = open('test.json', 'r')
values = json.load(jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
for template_variables in values['template_variables']:
    for key, value in template_variables.iteritems():
        print key, ':', value

Comment: You're asking about 3 different questions here. To get you started, you can update `values` with `values['template_variables'][0]['default'] = 'newvalue'`. This won't handle when there are multiple dicts in the list, but it's unclear what you want in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of json object as a dictionary.
try this.

```
import json
jsonData = '''{
  "board_title": "test",
  "read_only": false,
  "isIntegration": false,
  "board_bgtype": "board_graph",
  "created": "2017-08-16T06:40:47.158868+00:00",
  "original_title": "Revised_CID_Templating-test(cloned)",
  "modified": "2017-08-31T11:52:22.115661+00:00",
  "disableEditing": false,
  "height": 111,
  "width": "100%",
  "template_variables": [
    {
      "default": "identity",
      "prefix": "v1",
      "name": "env"
    }
  ],
  "created_by": {
    "disabled": false,
    "handle": "xx.com",
    "name": null,
    "is_admin": false,
    "role": null,
    "access_role": "st",
    "verified": true,
    "email": "xx.com",
    "icon": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/86fd6c17deba27cfc4081134a5bc0c6a?s=48&d=retro"
  }
}'''
jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)
print (jsonToPython['template_variables'][0]['default'])
jsonToPython['template_variables'][0]['default'] = 'test'
print (jsonToPython['template_variables'][0]['default'])
```

as you can see jsonToPython is being modified.